# Plotting desity wise scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have 2 lists x and y . I have plotted a scattered plot as shown in the image below
with the commands

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

[image: scattered plot of x, y]

I want to plot density plot from these 2 lists x, y (i.e) in highly dense area the color is dark (or different color) and in less dense area lighter color. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Maybe using a semi-transparency? `plt.scatter(x, y, alpha=.1)`. If there are many points, you might want to use a smaller size for the scatter dots. `plt.scatter(x, y, s=1, alpha=.1)`.

Comment: @JohanC can somehow get color into this? like red for highly dense area, green for medium, yellow for less dense area.

Comment: Maybe [Seaborn's 2D kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot)?  `sns.kdeplot(x, y, cmap='YlOrRd', shade=True, shade_lowest=False)` ?

Comment: Is seaborn very slow? I have a huge list, it isn't able to plot from last 3 hours. Any other option if you could recommend?

Comment: If you have millions of points, a [2D histogram](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) could be more adequate. ([Example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/scales/power_norm.html#sphx-glr-gallery-scales-power-norm-py))